# Bulk Uploading to MediaWiki (Hierarchical Structure)

Tags: bash, markdown, mediawiki, pandoc, mediawiki-extensions

I have lots of Markdown files each contained in a folder with the same name as Markdown file. I use Pandoc to generate the MediaWiki file in `Rendered` folder.

For Example

```
ComputerScience
  |
  ComputerScience.md
  |
  Rendered
  |  | 
  |  ComputerScience.wiki
  Image
  |  |
  |  Computer.png
  Resource
     |
     Algorithms.pdf
```

Every Markdown file has its own folder which contains other folders like `Image`, `Resource`, which are linked in the markdown file. To explain my structure: let me call the above structure as `ComputerScience Container`. Each markdown file has this `container`. These containers are classified in a hierarchical way - Several such containers can exist in a Folder (which I call here as, SuperFolder). These SuperFolder can Contain another SuperFolder. For example (The markdown folders are mentioned as Container):

```
Computer Science
  |
  Computer Science Container
  |
  Algorithms
  |  |
  |  Algorithms Container
  |  |
  |  DataStructure Container
  Architecture Container
```

In above Computer Science Super Folder consist of Containers as well as another SuperFolder called Algorithms.

How can I upload this kind of hierarchical structure into local mediawiki?

Also, I would like to edit Markdown files and generate the updated MediaWiki files. I hope to update the Mediawiki files using a script.

Any suggestions on how should I approach this?

Comment: I guess you could write a script that connects to the sql-db underlying your Mediawiki install and inserts those rows...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn a tool that's flexible and can be reused in the future, I'd look at [pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot). If you just want a quick one-off that can be used from bash, and the wiki is local, use [edit.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Edit.php).